# 2022 Potential Moderator Election: Community Interest Check

Tags: discussion, election

It's time for us to consider holding an election for moderators for Tor.

The last election we held was back in 2021, where we elected two moderators, and since then, one moderator resigned (Swangie), so we will be holding an election for another moderator.

So: we should hold a new election to get ourselves back up to a more regularly-available and active moderation team. To avoid finding ourselves in a situation where an election would fail due to an insufficient number of candidates, though, I'm posting this to try to assess the community members' willingness to step up and nominate themselves, when the actual election's nomination period starts.

Please leave an answer if you'd be willing to run for a moderator position, should we decide to run an election.

NOTE: This is not an official election nomination thread, just a "pulse check" to get a notion of how many people here would be willing to step up.

Currently, March 8th is the tentative date for such an election, starting with nominations, but only if we can get enough people willing to run for moderator positions.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, I'm still here and will be glad to help!